# java apps. string manipulation

Tags: string, jtextfield, string-length

I want to limit the no. of character that can be put on `JTextField` because on my database I have this column that has Sex,Status (which the no. of char. allowed is 1 only).

and Middle Initial (which the no. of char. allowed is 2 only).

This what I have in my mind :

(for Sex,Status column)

```
String text = jTextField2.getText();
        int count = text.();
        if (count>1) {
            (delete the next character that will be input)
        }
```

(for M.I. column)

```
String text = jTextField1.getText();
        int count = text.();
        if (count>2) {
            (delete the next character that will be input)
        }
```

is this possible? is there a command that will delete the next character, so the no. of char. is acceptable for my database?

Comment: Sorry, I put "==" instead of ">" , my bad.

Answer (score 1):

Sure. Just use [String#substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring(int,%20int)).

```
String middleInitial = "JKL";
middleInitial.substring(0, 2);
System.out.println(middleInitial); // => JK
```

Similarly, you can use `substring(0, 1)` for sex.

It might be better if sex is an enum, though.

```
public enum Sex {
  MALE("m"), FEMALE("f");

  final String symbol;
  private Sex(String symbol) {
    this.symbol = symbol;
  }
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

String sex = "male";
   Sex.valueOf(sex.toUpperCase());

Or directly

```
Sex.MALE;
```

Instead of a text field for sex, you might use a [JComboBox](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) so the user can only choose one of the two options. This way you're sure to have valid input.

Comment: I can use the coding that you posted but It's not the one that I'm looking for.

Comment: Can you give more input about what you're looking for then? Substring takes care of this line in your example: "(delete the next character that will be input)"

Comment: I will used that 'delete the next character that will be input' to all my jtextfield, like for first name, lastname, address, so on and so forth...